# How to get time.Tick to tick immediately

Tags: go, timer

I have a loop that iterates until a job is up and running:

```
ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 2)
defer ticker.Stop()

started := time.Now()
for now := range ticker.C {
    job, err := client.Job(jobID)
    switch err.(type) {
    case DoesNotExistError:
        continue
    case InternalError:
        return err
    }

    if job.State == "running" {
        break
    }

    if now.Sub(started) > time.Minute*2 {
        return fmt.Errorf("timed out waiting for job")
    }
}
```

Works great in production.  The only problem is that it makes my tests slow.  They all wait at least 2 seconds before completing.  Is there anyway to get `time.Tick` to tick immediately?

Comment: Whoops, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Set ticker and other durations to smaller values in tests.

Comment: These "jobs" are actually running on a remote service.  Though it is possible to have this program run a server locally and modify the remote service to accept subscriptions, that solution is much too heavy handed imo.

Comment: @JimB sorry for my ignorance, but what's the race condition you're referring to around `job.State`?  Is the assumption that `job` is a shared object?

Comment: Sorry, I was on mobile, and misread the code thinking that `job` came from outside the for loop.

Comment: @Xavi : wrap your code in a function, use variables for the ticker delay and the timeout value, set those variables to smaller values when testing.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Unfortunately, it [seems](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17601) that Go developers will not add such functionality in any foreseeable future, so we have to cope...

There are two common ways to use tickers:

### `for` loop

Given something like this:

```golang
ticker := time.NewTicker(period)
defer ticker.Stop()
for <- ticker.C {
    ...
}
```

Use:

```golang
ticker := time.NewTicker(period)
defer ticker.Stop()
for ; true; <- ticker.C {
    ...
}
```

### `for`-`select` loop

Given something like this:

```golang
interrupt := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
signal.Notify(interrupt, os.Interrupt)

ticker := time.NewTicker(period)
defer ticker.Stop()

loop:
for {
    select {
        case <- ticker.C: 
            f()
        case <- interrupt:
            break loop
    }
}
```

Use:

```golang
interrupt := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
signal.Notify(interrupt, os.Interrupt)

ticker := time.NewTicker(period)
defer ticker.Stop()

loop:
for {
    f()

    select {
        case <- ticker.C: 
            continue
        case <- interrupt:
            break loop
    }
}
```

### Why not just use `time.Tick()`?

> While Tick is useful for clients that have no need to shut down the Ticker, be aware that without a way to shut it down the underlying Ticker cannot be recovered by the garbage collector; it "leaks".

https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Tick

Comment: Does `<- time.Tick(period)` create a Ticker on each iteration? According to document, the Ticker created by Tick cannot be garbage-collected. This terrifies me.

Comment: @youfu You are absolutely right! I have just edited my answer.

Answer (score 28):

```
ticker := time.NewTicker(period)
for ; true; <-ticker.C {
    ...
}
```

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17601

Comment: Just to add to this. If you don't want to lose the value you get from the chan you can do `for t := time.Now(); true; t = <-ticker.C {`

Comment: This solutions is also more elegant in cases you need to call continue, inside the for block

Answer (score 6):

The actual implementation of `Ticker` internally is pretty complicated. But you can wrap it with a goroutine:

```
func NewTicker(delay, repeat time.Duration) *time.Ticker {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(repeat)
    oc := ticker.C
    nc := make(chan time.Time, 1)
    go func() {
        nc <- time.Now()
        for tm := range oc {
            nc <- tm
        }
    }()
    ticker.C = nc
    return ticker
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just send to the ticker channel immediately ?

Comment: It's a receive only channel: `type Ticker struct {
    C <-chan Time // The channel on which the ticks are delivered.
    // contains filtered or unexported fields
}`

Comment: Why `delay` arg used here?

Comment: "delay" is not used. Also i want point out that this timer is not guaranteed to fire instantly, as the `go func(){ }` part is sheduled, but not executed for sure. 
But asides from that nitpicking this should be the accepted answer imho

Answer (score 6):

If you want to check the job right away, don't use the ticker as the condition in the for loop. For example:

```
ticker := time.NewTicker(2 * time.Second)
defer ticker.Stop()

started := time.Now()
for {
    job, err := client.Job(jobID)
    if err == InternalError {
        return err
    }

    if job.State == "running" {
        break
    }

    now := <-ticker.C
    if now.Sub(started) > 2*time.Minute {
        return fmt.Errorf("timed out waiting for job")
    }
}
```

If you do still need to check for `DoesNotExistError`, you want to make sure you do it after the ticker so you don't have a busy-wait.

Comment: This is the right solution imo -- also present in the stdlib, see https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/server.go#L2648

Answer (score 3):

I cooked up something like this

```
func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    callme := func() {
        // do somethign more
        fmt.Println("callme", time.Since(t))
    }
    ticker := time.NewTicker(10 * time.Second)
    first := make(chan bool, 1)
    first <- true
    for {
        select {
        case <-ticker.C:
            callme()
        case <-first:
            callme()
        }
        t = time.Now()
    }
    close(first)
}
```

Comment: Isn't it just easier and also clean to call callme() just beofre the for loop? What would be the advantage of complicating it?

Answer (score 3):

How about using Timer instead of Ticker? Timer can be started with zero duration and then reset to the desired duration value:

```golang
timer := time.NewTimer(0)
defer timer.Stop()

for {
    select {
        case <-timer.C:
            timer.Reset(interval)
            job()
        case <-ctx.Done():
            break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be an interesting alternative for the `for-select` loop, specially if the contents of the `case` are not a simple function:

Having:

```golang
interrupt := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
signal.Notify(interrupt, os.Interrupt)

ticker := time.NewTicker(period)
defer ticker.Stop()

loop:
for {
    select {
        case <- ticker.C: 
            f()
        case <- interrupt:
            break loop
    }
}
```

Use:

```golang
interrupt := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
signal.Notify(interrupt, os.Interrupt)

ticker := time.NewTicker(period)
defer ticker.Stop()
firstTick := false

// create a wrapper of the ticker that ticks the first time immediately
tickerChan := func() <-chan time.Time {
  if !firstTick {
    firstTick = true
    c := make(chan time.Time, 1)
    c <- time.Now()
    return c
  }

  return ticker.C
}

loop:
for {
    select {
        case <- tickerChan(): 
            f()
        case <- interrupt:
            break loop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also drain the channel at the end of the loop:

```golang
t := time.NewTicker(period)
defer t.Stop()

for {
    ...
    
    <-t.C
}
```