# Make time ticker procedure more monotonic

Tags: go

I have several goroutines in my golang program, one of which has an infinite loop that runs a ticker for 20 milliseconds. Inside this goroutine there are no heavy operations and shared data, however, the ticker does not work accurately - the response spread is from 15 to 40 milliseconds, and I need to be as accurate as possible to 20. I assume this is due to competition with other coroutines. The ticker procedure is:

```
func (v *vocoderFile) sendAudioLoop() {
    targetInterval := 20 * time.Millisecond
    for {

        startTime := time.Now()

        // Some procedure.....

        elapsed := time.Since(startTime)
        if elapsed < targetInterval {
            time.Sleep(targetInterval - elapsed)
        }
    }
}
```

Also I have tested other variant - similar result:

```
func (v *vocoderFile) sendAudioLoop() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(20 * time.Millisecond)
    for {
        <-ticker.C

        // Some procedure.....
    }
}
```

How can I make sendAudioLoop working more monotonic?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to establish for yourself the acceptable lower and upper bounds for your program's timing needs, and then over-sample and test for the correct interval:

```golang
const (
    lower = 19_900 * time.Microsecond
    upper = 20_100 * time.Microsecond
)

// pulse does something every 20ms +/-.1ms
func pulse() {
    var (
        last    = time.Now()
        elapsed time.Duration
    )

    ticker := time.NewTicker(500 * time.Microsecond)
    for now := range ticker.C {
        elapsed = now.Sub(last)
        if elapsed > lower {
            // Some procedure...
            last = now
        }
    }
}
```

Even though the ticker's period of 500µs is coarser than the margin of +/- 100µs, I haven't seen interval errors in a test run of 1000 pulses (20s).

I don't know much about Go's scheduler, and the internals of timing.  I read [this issue on the performance of Sleep and Ticker](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27707), and that gave me some ideas about performance and patterns.  This SO, [Sleep() or Timer(), Go idiomatic?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53315789/246801), gave me the idea that I should probably just use Timer.

I've included a complete program to generate about 1000 test pulses and some stats like:

```
...5s elapsed
...5s elapsed
...5s elapsed
...5s elapsed
1000 pulses: 19.941ms...20.061916ms
```

Some times (like launching the Activity Monitor in macOS, mid-run), my system was stressed enough to be late by a factor of 3:

```
...
9 too-long pulses:
  20.173042ms
  20.294166ms
  20.314125ms
  20.333667ms
  20.611917ms
  21.762083ms
  22.614583ms
  22.809292ms
  58.68725ms
```

Usually, though, even with the CPU pegged at 100%, the Ticker was within my 100µs bounds.

```golang
func main() {
    done := time.After(20*time.Second + 1*time.Millisecond) // run time limit
    tickTock := time.NewTicker(5 * time.Second)             // incremental print msg

    go randomWork() // pegs CPU at about 100%

    chP := make(chan time.Duration)
    go pulse(chP)

    pulses := make([]time.Duration, 0)
loop:
    for {
        select {
        case d := <-chP:
            pulses = append(pulses, d)
        case <-tickTock.C:
            fmt.Println("...5s elapsed")
        case <-done:
            break loop
        }
    }

    printStats(pulses)
}

const (
    lower = 19_900 * time.Microsecond
    upper = 20_100 * time.Microsecond
)

// pulse does something every 20ms +/-.1ms
func pulse(ch chan<- time.Duration) {
    var (
        last    = time.Now()
        elapsed time.Duration
    )

    ticker := time.NewTicker(500 * time.Microsecond)
    for now := range ticker.C {
        elapsed = now.Sub(last)
        if elapsed > lower {
            // Some procedure...
            ch <- elapsed
            last = now
        }
    }
}

func randomWork() {
    for {
        x := 0
        for i := 0; i < rand.Intn(1e7); i++ {
            x = i
        }
        x = x // silence "unused x" error
    }
}

func printStats(pulses []time.Duration) {
    sort.Slice(pulses, func(i, j int) bool { return pulses[i] < pulses[j] })

    tooShort := make([]time.Duration, 0)
    tooLong := make([]time.Duration, 0)
    for _, d := range pulses {
        if d < lower {
            tooShort = append(tooShort, d)
        }
        if d > upper {
            tooLong = append(tooLong, d)
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("%d pulses: %v...%v\n", len(pulses), pulses[0], pulses[len(pulses)-1])

    if len(tooShort) > 0 {
        fmt.Printf("%d too-short pulses:\n", len(tooShort))
        for _, d := range tooShort {
            fmt.Printf("  %v\n", d)
        }
    }

    if len(tooLong) > 0 {
        fmt.Printf("%d too-long pulses:\n", len(tooLong))
        for _, d := range tooLong {
            fmt.Printf("  %v\n", d)
        }
    }
}
```